# Dockerfile run a script on background without exit it

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I try to execute a binary on background on docker. On linux server, I used
./binary config.xml &

So, I try the execution on docker

Dockerfile

```
COPY dockerrun.sh /usr/local/bin/dokcerrun.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vectorrun.sh
RUN bash -c "sh /usr/local/bin/vectorrun.sh"
```

dockerrun.sh

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/root/binary --config /root/config.xml &
```

Unfortunately, when I connected on docker
docker build .
docker run -ti id bash

I don't see my process binary execution with : ps -ef | grep binary

I try with ENTRYPOINT instruction :

```
COPY dockerrun.sh /usr/local/bin/dockerrun.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dockerrun.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/dockerrun.sh"]

docker build .
docker run -ti id
```

but my container is exited (0) directly and is not running

Comment: [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) is only executed at the build time of the image. Not at runtime of the container. If you want a process to be running in the container, you have to add it to the `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: Thanks for your replying, I changed to ENTRYPOINT, but the docker directlly exited (0), I cannot to connect, what I should do ?

Comment: The container exits, once the command executed in `ENTRYPOINT` ends. So if your entrypoint command is only calling a binary to run in background, the command will end immediately and so will the container. Why do you even want to run that binary in background if the only purpose of that container seems to be running that binary? Just set the ENTRYPOINT to that binary and the container will run, while the binary is running.

Comment: A Docker container runs one process, and it must be a foreground process.  When the process exits the container exits too.  If you need multiple processes a typical approach is to use multiple containers.  I might dispense with this script altogether (and prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`); can you have the container run `CMD /root/binary --config /root/config.xml`?